# How to create a SOAP Document using XmlDocument

Tags: soap, windows-runtime, winjs

How do you create a SOAP document when using WinJS and the Windows runtime?

For reference, a SOAP document should be structured like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetTotals xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/totals">
    </m:GetTotals>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I was using TypeScript with WinJS, but my combinations have just not worked. Currently, I've got this segment of code:

```js
private _writeHeader() : Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.IXmlElement {
    var xml = this._xmlDocument;
    var env = xml.createElementNS("soap", "Envelope");
    env.setAttributeNS("xmlns", "soap", 
          "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    var body = xml.createElementNS("soap", "Body");
    env.appendChild(body);
    xml.appendChild(env);

    return body;
}
```

Which produces this:

```xml
<Envelope xmlns="soap" 
          xmlns:ns0="xmlns" 
          ns0:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body/>
</Envelope>"
```

Unfortunately, the `XDocument` classes aren't available. I'll insert other elements into the `Body` later.

(I'll certainly be happy with a JavaScript solution, as there's not much TypeScript helps with here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp) and [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it can be done with the following code.

```
    var n = 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope';
    var e = createElement('soap', 'Envelope', n);
    var h = createElement('soap', 'Header', n);
    e.appendChild(h);
    var body = createElement('soap', 'body', n);
    e.appendChild(body);
    var getTotals = createElement('m', 'GetTotals', 'http://www.example.org/totals');
    body.appendChild(getTotals);
    var string = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(e);
    console.log(string);

    function createElement(prefix, name, nsp)
    {
        var e;
        var tag = prefix + ':' + name;
        if (nsp)
            e = document.createElementNS(nsp, tag);
        else
            e = document.createElement(tag);

        // without any content, node end tag is not added by the xml serializer.
        var empty = document.createTextNode('\n');
        e.appendChild(empty);
        return e;
    }
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach that I hadn't considered.

Comment: While I ended up going with the solution I presented (as I preferred not using the DOM to build Xml), I'll accept your answer as it was spot on to the original.

Answer (score 0):

While the resulting XML isn't exactly what I wanted, it should be semantically equivalent when using the following code:

```js
private _writeHeader() : Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.IXmlElement {
    var xml = this._xmlDocument;    
    var soapUri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";      
    var env = xml.createElementNS(soapUri, "Envelope");           
    var body = xml.createElementNS(soapUri, "Body");
    env.appendChild(body);
    xml.appendChild(env);

    return body;
}
```

Results in:

```xml
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body/></Envelope>
```

(If someone knows how to get it precisely what I specified, I'll accept your answer.)